# What is "Private Beta"?

Tags: bug

I was looking at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking. There is a list of links, including:

- [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta)

What's this? Something left over from an older, better, happier time? Is it still relevant?

Comment: Annoyingly, those who were on Chiphacker before it was combined to the current EE site didn't get the badge for being in the beta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no longer relevant to EE.SE, but every SE site goes through a "private beta" stage as part of its development, and this FAQ is part of the standard boilerplate that goes along with that.